# Using proj to convert EPSG:2263 to WGS84

Tags: qgis, wgs84, proj, epsg, cs2cs

I have input data in EPSG:2263 with X and Y coordinates such as:

```
X,Y
987043,206407
982441,212359
990907,209020
```

(these locations are within NYC).

I need to convert these to WGS84.  Using QGIS if I import these coordinates and tell it the input data is in "EPSG:2263, NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS)" successfully imports the coordinates and renders them correctly (e.g. if overlaid over a WGS84 map).

It gives me this as the conversion options:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666  +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

However, if I try to manually convert a point on the command line, for example:

```
cs2cs +proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs -f '%.8f'
987043,206407
-73.99000712    40.16666623 0.00000000,206407
```

The resulting point is obviously *not* correct and (if shown on Google Earth) is off the coast of New Jersey.

I'll admit projections and coordinate systems and converting between them does still quite baffle me...

Suggestions for how I should be adjusting those `cs2cs` options to get a correct conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
cs2cs +proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f %%.8f<nad.txt >out.txt
```

with

```
987043 206407
```

in the input file `nad.txt` to get this output:

```
-73.98992216    40.73321572 0.00000000
```

Note that input values have to be delimited by blanks, not commas.

Comment: So I was missing the to-projection; I thought it defaulted to EPSG:4326.  And my input was comma-delimited instead of space-delimited.