# Convert EPSG:2263 LiDAR data to EPSG:4326 to use with FSX

Tags: convert, lidar, epsg, las, xyz

I have LiDAR (las) input files in EPSG:2263 (NAD83, NY state plane, feet_US) aquired from https://gis.ny.gov/elevation/ and want to convert those file to EPSG:4326 (WGS84) for use in MS Flight Simulator. I tried gdal / pdal/ liblas, lastools etc. but it seems impossible to do the right conversion. I've seen a similar question ([Using proj to convert EPSG:2263 to WGS84](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153126/using-proj-to-convert-epsg2263-to-wgs84)) but there are only pairs of x and y coordinates converted. I can't see an option for z (Height) coordinates.

I have tried to create a delimitered text file first with las2txt, and then i used `gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:2263 -t_srs EPSG:4326 <in.txt >out.txt`. It produces a text file with lat long coordinates, but the conversion is somehow wrong (see image).

[image: text file rendered in CloudCompare]

What is the proper way to do the conversion?

Comment: Both EPSG:2263 and EPSG:4326 are 2D coordinate reference systems, so not sure why you are expecting a z conversion

Comment: there are x y z coordinates, it seems proj only expect x and y , if i convert the file using proj, the output for x and y is "*", like * * z. Not sure what is wrong there. I used the exact same method like in the above linked thread. By z conversion i mean need to convert the source from feet into meter in the target.

Comment: What if you convert to [epsg:4979](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4979)

Comment: I can try it as a second step but FSX works only with EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VT Builder (http://vterrain.org/) can actually do it. It takes state plane coordinate systems as input and can convert it to any desired output (EPSG:4326 in my case).